# Unable to cast object of type Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.RuntimeProperty to type Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Property

Tags: entity-framework-core, epplus, .net-7.0

I couldn't iterate the propsToBeHeaders variable. Here I am getting the properties with excel column header but I couldn't iterate over the properties because it throws this error, Unable to cast object of type Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.RuntimeProperty to type Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Property. Here I have provided the infrastructure layer GenerateTemplate Interface implementation and One from the domains(Models).

```cs
public DataImportHelper(EMSDBContext dbContext, IReflectionHelper reflectionHelper, IHostEnvironment environment)
{
    _dbContext = dbContext;
    this.reflectionHelper = reflectionHelper;
    _environment = environment;
}

public async Task<MemoryStream> GenerateTemplate(string model)
{
    // Get ClrType of selected entity type
    var clrType = typeof(Occupation).Assembly.DefinedTypes.Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Name.Equals(model)).FirstOrDefault();
    Type type = clrType;
    var objectType = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    var ent = _dbContext.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(q => q.ClrType == type).Single();

    // Retrieve all columns with excel column header values
    //IEnumerable<IProperty> props = from t in ent.GetProperties().OrderBy(f => f.FieldInfo?.MetadataToken)
    //                               let attributes = t?.PropertyInfo?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExcelColumnAttribute), true)
    //                               where attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0
    //                               select t as Property;
    var props = ent.GetProperties()
        .OrderBy(f => f.FieldInfo?.MetadataToken)
        .Where(t => t?.PropertyInfo?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExcelColumnAttribute), true) is Attribute[] attributes && attributes.Length > 0)
        .Select(t => t as IProperty);

    IEnumerable<IProperty> propsToBeHeaders = props.ToList();  // Optional: Convert the result to a list if required



    // Create and Return an Excel Sheet(Template)
    if (propsToBeHeaders != null)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
        {

            ExcelWorksheet sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(model);
            int i = 1;
            List<string> headers = new List<string> { };
            foreach (Property prop in propsToBeHeaders)
            {
                ExcelColumnAttribute attr = (ExcelColumnAttribute)prop.PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExcelColumnAttribute)).FirstOrDefault();
                sheet.Cells[1, i].Value = attr.Header;
                await SetWorkSheetValidationRules(package, sheet, prop, 2, i, 1048576, i);
                i++;
            }

            sheet.Row(1).Style.Font.Size = 12;
            sheet.Row(1).Style.Locked = true;
            sheet.Row(1).Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.DarkBlue);
            sheet.Row(1).Height = 30;
            sheet.Row(1).Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Center;
            sheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
            package.SaveAs(stream);
        }

        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream;
    }

    return null;
}
```

```cs
public class Occupation : Entity
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the occupation.
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Occupation Name")]
    [ExcelColumn(Header = "Occupation Name")]
    public string OccupationName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the description of the occupation.
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    [ExcelColumn(Header = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? You don't need reflection or so much code to work either with EF Core or EPPlus. You can fill an EPPlus sheet from a list of objects with a single call, `ws.Cells.LoadFromCollection(theList);`. You can also use `LoadFromDataReader` if the data comes from a database.

Comment: I removed the `clean-architecture` and `cqrs` tags because they have nothing to do with the question. It's hard to understand what the question is to be honest. The code is certainly not needed and confusing. [EPPlus attributes](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/wiki/LoadFromCollection-using-Attributes) are `EpplusTableColumn`, `EpplusIgnore` etc, not `ExcelColumn`

Comment: What I am trying to do is not exporting data from database but Generating an empty template to be used by a user and later to be imported.

Comment: I can change the ExcelColumn to EpplusTableColumn i think It doesn't have much difference.  And to elaborate the question, I have to export templates by getting the excel headers(Properties of the a  table at a time).

Comment: It makes a huge difference - EPPlus only recoginzes its own attributes. Even if you only want a template, there's no reason for any of this code. You could just create an empy list of your target objects and use them with `LoadFromCollection`. That's a single line in a generic method: `var range=sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(new List<T>());`. EPPlus will recognize its own attributes and apply them

Comment: I added an answer that shows how to generate the "template" in a single call to `LoadFromCollection` without any attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is already provided by EPPlus and its [Import functions](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/wiki/Import) like [LoadFromCollection](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/wiki/LoadFromCollection), [LoadFromDataTable](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/wiki/LoadFromDataTable) and more. The methods offer several ways to customize the table header, table and cell styles.

The question's desired output can be generated with a single call to `LoadFromCollection<T>`. Since the method is generic, any type can be used :

```
var items = new List<T>();
...
using (var pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
    var sheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("sheet");

    var range = sheet.Cells["C1"].LoadFromCollection(items, c => {
        c.PrintHeaders = true;
        c.TableStyle = TableStyles.Light9;
        c.HeaderParsingType = HeaderParsingTypes.CamelCaseToSpace;
    });
}
```

This can be used to create a "template" by using a empty enumerable:

```
async Task GenerateTemplateAsync<T>(FileInfo file)
{
    using var package = new ExcelPackage(file);
    var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
    var range=sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(Enumerable.Empty<T>(),c => {
        c.PrintHeaders = true;
        c.TableStyle = TableStyles.Light9;
        c.HeaderParsingType = HeaderParsingTypes.CamelCaseToSpace;
    });
    range.AutoFitColumns();
    await package.SaveAsync();
}
```

This can be called by simply passing the type :

```
public record Occupation(string OccupationName ,string Description);
...
await CreateTemplateAsync<Occupation>(new FileInfo("Template.xlsx"));
```

The only change needed to generate the file in memory is to pass a MemoryStream to ExcelPackage :

```
MemoryStream GenerateTemplate<T>()
{
    var stream=new MemoryStream();
    using var package = new ExcelPackage(stream);

    var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
    var range = sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(Enumerable.Empty<T>(), c => {
        c.PrintHeaders = true;
        c.TableStyle = TableStyles.Light9;
        c.HeaderParsingType = HeaderParsingTypes.CamelCaseToSpace;
    });
    range.AutoFitColumns();
    package.Save();

    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}
```

There's no I/O involved when writing to memory so there's no need to use `SaveAsync`.

**Header Names**

Out of the box, `_` is converted to   so the header `Occupation_Name` becomes `Occupation Name`. A different convention can be specified through the [HeaderParsingType](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/wiki/LoadFromCollection#headerparsingtype) configuration property. `HeaderParsingTypes.CamelCaseToSpace` will convert `OccupationName` to `Occupation Name`.

The name can also be specified through the `System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute` or `System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute` attributes which are also used to specify headers in GUI elements

Even more formatting options are provided through EPPlus's own [Attributes](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/wiki/LoadFromCollection-using-Attributes) like `EpplusIgnore`, `EpplusFormulaTableColumn`, `EpplusTableColumn`. These are useful when we use a separate DTO type for Excel generation, to avoid littering the entity or data DTOs,

Comment: Yeah This is useful, You have provided an answer for Occupation only, but the only table to be evaluated is not only Occupation that's why I need to read all the headers from the Entity.

Comment: And from the Occupation table I need only some attributes to be headers, my code is trying to get attributes with column headers, Can you help me with that?

Comment: I answered all that, with links to the various ways you can do it. You can write a LINQ query to Select just the columns you want, you can use separate Excel DTOs for your reports, which you should do anyway, you can use `EpplusIgnore` attributes. If you want to select columns dynamically, it's probably better to avoid EF Core and construct the query yourself, either directly or using a SQL builder library, and use `LoadFromDataReader` to load the results into an Excel sheet

Comment: `is not only Occupation` the code I posted works with any class. EPPlus itself finds the properties and headers. You don't need to do that yourself.